# If $H\leq G, N \trianglelefteq G$ then $HN \leqslant G$, alternative proof

Tags: group-theory

> If $H\leq G, N \trianglelefteq G$ then $HN \leqslant G$

I know of the proof which proceeds like this:

- $HN=NH$ which is easy to prove
- taking $h_1n_1, h_2n_2 \in HN$ it is easy to prove $h_1n_1(h_2n_2)^{-1} \in HN$

done

#### Alternative

My textbook writes as a remark

> Notice how $(H^\pi)^{\pi^{-1}} = HN$ where $\pi$ is the canonical projection of $G$ to $G/N$. This is an alternative way to prove $HN\leqslant G$.

I don't really see why this is the case. I see that $(H^\pi)^{\pi^{-1}} = HN$ and then would reason like:

Since $\pi$ is a groupmorphism $H^\pi \leq G/N$ as the image of a subgroup  of $G$. If I could prove that $\pi^{-1}$ is a groupmorphism as well then once again $(H^\pi)^{\pi^{-1}}$ would be the image of a subgroup in $G/N$ which is a subgroup of $G$.

The problem is that $\pi^{-1}$ is not a group morphism? It doesn't seem to be a well defined function. I guess I should write $\pi^{-1}$ as

$$\begin{align}
\pi^{-1}:  & G/N \to \mathcal{P}(G)\\
&gN \mapsto \{\tilde{g} \in G: \tilde{g} N = g N\}
\end{align}$$
Where $\mathcal{P}(G)$ is the power set of $G$. But then $\mathcal{P}(G)$ hardly seems like a group.

Comment: $\pi^{-1}$ is a well defined function, which maps (subgroups of $G/N$) to (subgroups of $G$ containing $N$).  This is the fourth "correspondence" isomorphism theorem.